# Como puedo llamar a una function en controladores de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Por ejemplo, en este controlador tengo esas 2 funciones, pero como pueden ver, en la función getHome() al llamar al otro método me marca error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder al metodo `obtenerEvento` dentro del controlador puedes usar:

`$this->obtenerEvento($tipoUser, $userID);`

Para acceder a cualquier otro metodo o propiedad del controlador puedes usar la pseudo-variable `$this`

Aca te dejo unas referencias por si queres leer mas:

- [Manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- [StackOverflow (Ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)